# LinearLayout animation not showing data from within the layout after second usage

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I am using an animation for a LinearLayout, but after I show the data from within the layout for the second time its contents do not get shown.

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/invoiceCardView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="0.1"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <com.rey.material.widget.CheckBox
                            android:id="@+id/selectInvoice"
                            style="@style/Material.Drawable.CheckBox"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.33"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/invoiceId"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="#00000003"
                                android:textColor="#5d9cec"
                                android:textSize="18sp" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/invoiceStatus"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="0.37"
                                android:background="#26C6DA"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="active"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                        </LinearLayout>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight="0.25"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/invoiceAmount"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="$ 222,064.00"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight="0.1"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <com.mikepenz.iconics.view.IconicsImageView
                            android:id="@+id/showDetailsArrow"
                            android:layout_width="20dp"
                            android:layout_height="20dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            app:iiv_color="@color/colorGrey"
                            app:iiv_icon="faw-angle-down" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/invoiceDetails"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:visibility="gone">

                    <TableLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

                        <TableRow
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:background="@color/appBlack">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/textView12"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Details"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                                android:textSize="16sp"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />
                        </TableRow>

                        <TableRow
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:gravity="left"
                                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                                android:text="Date Sent"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorGrey" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/dateSent"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:gravity="right"
                                android:text="7/27/2017"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                        </TableRow>

                        <TableRow
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/textView18"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:gravity="left"
                                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                                android:text="Date Paid"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorGrey" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/datePaid"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:gravity="right"
                                android:text="7/27/2017"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />
                        </TableRow>

                        <TableRow
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/textView21"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:gravity="left"
                                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                                android:text="Days Past Due"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorGrey" />

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
                                android:orientation="vertical">

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/daysPastDue"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:background="#f00000"
                                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                                    android:text="70 days"
                                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                                    android:textStyle="bold" />
                            </LinearLayout>

                        </TableRow>

                        <TableRow
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:gravity="left"
                                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                                android:text="@string/name"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorGrey" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/name"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:gravity="right"
                                android:text="Test"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />
                        </TableRow>

                        <TableRow
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:gravity="left"
                                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                                android:text="Email"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorGrey" />

                            <HorizontalScrollView
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:fillViewport="true">

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                                    <TextView
                                        android:id="@+id/email"
                                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_weight="1"
                                        android:gravity="right"
                                        android:text="test@email.com"
                                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                                </LinearLayout>
                            </HorizontalScrollView>
                        </TableRow>

                        <TableRow
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:gravity="left"
                                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                                android:text="Balance"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorGrey" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/balance"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:gravity="right"
                                android:text="$ 420.00"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />
                        </TableRow>

                        <TableRow
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:gravity="left"
                                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                                android:text="Preview"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorGrey" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/balance"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:gravity="right"
                                android:text="View"
                                android:textColor="#5d9cec" />
                        </TableRow>

                        <TableRow
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical">

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                                android:gravity="left"
                                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                                android:text="Actions"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorGrey" />

                            <fr.ganfra.materialspinner.MaterialSpinner
                                android:id="@+id/actions"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorGrey"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                app:ms_arrowColor="@color/colorGrey"
                                app:ms_enableFloatingLabel="false"
                                app:ms_hint="Select Action"
                                app:ms_hintColor="@color/colorGrey"
                                app:ms_hintTextSize="14sp" />

                        </TableRow>

                    </TableLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Java:

```
//variable declaration    
private boolean showRowDetails = false;
showRowDetails = !showRowDetails;
final LinearLayout invoiceDetails = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.invoiceDetails);
invoiceDetails.setAlpha(0.0f);
IconicsImageView showDetailsArrow = (IconicsImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.showDetailsArrow);
if(showRowDetails){
    invoiceDetails.animate()
            .translationY(invoiceDetails.getHeight())
            .alpha(1.0f)
            .setDuration(800)
            .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                    invoiceDetails.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
    showDetailsArrow.setImageDrawable(
            new IconicsDrawable(context)
                    .icon("faw-angle-up")
                    .color(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorGrey))
    );
}
else {
    invoiceDetails.animate()
            .translationY(0)
            .alpha(0.0f)
            .setDuration(800)
            .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                    invoiceDetails.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
    showDetailsArrow.setImageDrawable(
            new IconicsDrawable(context)
                    .icon("faw-angle-down")
                    .color(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorGrey))
    );
}
```

Hidden data:
[image: hidden data]

Data shown the first time:

[image]

Data shown the second time after collapsing the view:

[image]

Any idea why is this happening? Thank you all for your time!

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced similar issues like this before where animations don't properly "fill" the before and after states of the animation on the `View`. I'm not sure if this will fix you issue exactly, but try to implement a similar solution like this:

The idea is that you should set the pre-state of the `View` before starting the animator and then in the `onAnimationEnd(Animator)` set the post-state of the animation on the object. So for example, in your show animation (when `showRowDetails` is `true`), try this:

```
invoiceDetails.setAlpha(0.0f);
invoiceDetails.setTranslationY(0);
invoiceDetails.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
final int height = invoiceDetails.getHeight();
invoiceDetails.animate()
    .translationY(height)
    .alpha(1.0f)
    .setDuration(800)
    .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            invoiceDetails.setAlpha(1.0f);
            invoiceDetails.setTranslationY(height);
        }
    }).start();
```

Notice a few things here:

1. Move `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` before starting the animation because you want the `View` to already be visible so you can see the animation actually happening.
2. Set the `View`'s pre-state before starting the animation.
3. Set the `View`'s post-state in `onAnimationEnd()`.
4. Remove `super.onAnimationEnd(animator)`, this is not needed.

I hope this explanation makes sense. My exact solution might not work immediately, but the idea should be the same. You'll need to play around and see if that works for you. Hope this helps!

Comment: You forgot to call `start()` at the end.

Comment: @Brian It is very weird, even tho' I made these changes now on the second tap I can see the contents getting slide out of the linear layout and disappearing

Comment: Ah I've also seen this similar issue before, never understood why Android animations are such a headache sometimes! Did you also implement the pre-state and post-change changes to your hiding animation as well?